# How can I add data to the last row of any csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add `kalyanmohanty` `22:54:42` `03-06-2020` to the `8th` row in the place of `NaN`.  How can I do this using pandas or python csv moddule

[image: csv file]

Comment: Could you, please, clarify what your problem is exactly? Do you have problems with reading CSV? Or maybe locating the last row? Or do you have problems with replacing values by given index and columns in pandas DataFrame? In the current state I don't see this quetion being useful to future visitors and voting to close it as "needing more focus".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using CSV**

Updates last row of CSV file

```
import csv

with open('csv_file.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
  # All rows
  rows = list(reader)
  # Update last row
  rows[-1].update({'Name':'kalyanmohanty', 'Time': '22:54:42', 'Date': '03-06-2020'})

with open('csv_file.csv', 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = rows[-1].keys())
  writer.writeheader()
  writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the name of your dataframe is `df`, you can use this :

```
df.loc[df.shape[0]-1,['Name','Time','Date']] = ['kalyanmohanty', '22:54:42','03-06-2020']
```

Comment: Thank you so much . If I have to add it in the last row . When the more data will be added then the last row will not be same . then 7 will not work . I have tried with -1 . but is creating another row at last and adding to it

Comment: That's strange why `-1` doesn't work Anyway, you can try with `df.shape[0]-1`